# FailedToStartRouteException exception while using camel-spring-boot, amqp and kafka starters with SpringBoot, unable to find connectionFactory bean

Tags: apache-camel, spring-amqp, spring-camel

I am creating an application using Apache Camel to transfer messages from AMQP to Kafka. Code can also be seen here - https://github.com/prashantbhardwaj/qpid-to-kafka-using-camel

I thought of creating it as standalone SpringBoot app using spring, amqp and kafka starters. Created a route like

```
@Component
public class QpidToKafkaRoute extends RouteBuilder {

  public void configure() throws Exception {
      from("amqp:queue:destinationName")
              .to("kafka:topic");
  }
}
```

And SpringBoot application configuration is

```java
@SpringBootApplication
    public class CamelSpringJmsKafkaApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(CamelSpringJmsKafkaApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public JmsConnectionFactory jmsConnectionFactory(@Value("${qpidUser}") String qpidUser, @Value("${qpidPassword}") String qpidPassword, @Value("${qpidBrokerUrl}") String qpidBrokerUrl) {
        JmsConnectionFactory jmsConnectionFactory = new JmsConnectionFactory(qpidPassword, qpidPassword, qpidBrokerUrl);
        return jmsConnectionFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public CachingConnectionFactory jmsCachingConnectionFactory(JmsConnectionFactory jmsConnectionFactory) {
        CachingConnectionFactory cachingConnectionFactory = new CachingConnectionFactory(jmsConnectionFactory);

        return cachingConnectionFactory;
    }
```

jmsConnectionFactory bean which is created using Spring Bean annotation should be picked by amqp starter and should be injected into the route. But it is not happening. When I started this application, I got following exception -

```
org.apache.camel.FailedToStartRouteException: Failed to start route route1 because of Route(route1)[From[amqp:queue:destinationName] -> [To[kafka:.

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: connectionFactory must be specified
```

If I am not wrong connectionFactory should be created automatically if I pass right properties in application.properties file.

My application.properties file looks like :

```
camel.springboot.main-run-controller = true
camel.component.amqp.enabled = true
camel.component.amqp.connection-factory = jmsCachingConnectionFactory
camel.component.amqp.async-consumer = true
camel.component.amqp.concurrent-consumers = 1
camel.component.amqp.map-jms-message = true
camel.component.amqp.test-connection-on-startup = true
camel.component.kafka.brokers = localhost:9092
qpidBrokerUrl = amqp://localhost:5672?jms.username=guest&jms.password=guest&jms.clientID=clientid2&amqp.vhost=default
qpidUser = guest
qpidPassword = guest
```

Could you please help suggest why during autoconfiguring connectionFactory object is not being used? When I debug this code, I can clearly see that connectionFactory bean is getting created.

I can even see one more log line -

```
CamelContext has only been running for less than a second. If you intend to run Camel for a longer time then you can set the property camel.springboot.main-run-controller=true in application.properties or add spring-boot-starter-web JAR to the classpath.
```

however if you see my application.properties file, required property is present at the very first line.

One more log line, I can see at the beginning of application startup -

```
[main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.apache.camel.spring.boot.CamelAutoConfiguration' of type [org.apache.camel.spring.boot.CamelAutoConfiguration] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
```

Is this log line suggesting anything?

Note - One interesting fact that exactly same code was running fine last night, just restarted my desktop and there is not even a single word changed and now it is throwing exception.

Comment: Can you post the complete exception?

Comment: You have 2 jms connection factory - even if you specify primary on one of them, there are still 2 in the registry. And therefore you need to configure the jms Camel component which one to use. Or change your code to only have 1 jms connection factory @Bean

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Commenting out one connection factory solved the issue. However, it raises couple of questions - 1. Shouldn't it look by connection factory bean name as mentioned in camel.component.amqp.connection-factory = jmsCachingConnectionFactory? Seems like amqp-starter is not using amqp related property values mentioned in application.properties. 2. Why do we need to register AMQPComponent as a bean, shouldn't this be the job of camel-amqp-starter to create one by using the properties provided in application.properties. Checked in the working code.

Answer (score 1):

This just refers to an interface

```
camel.component.amqp.connection-factory = javax.jms.ConnectionFactory
```

Instead it should refer to an existing factory instance, such as

```
camel.component.amqp.connection-factory = #myFactory
```

Which you can setup via spring boot `@Bean` annotation style.